# Ionic 3 : arrays pointing on same values

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm developing a IOnic 3 application and I'm getting an issue on arrays in my component
I'm using an array to display my user list (sortedUtilisateurs) and I want a similar array with the same values on (tabSearch) but I don't want it to change when the first one change.

Unfortunatly sortedUtilisateurs changes as tabSearch changes on my view...

**My component constructor below**

```
constructor(
    public nav: NavController,
    public params: NavParams, 
    public utilisateurMetier : UtilisateurMetier, 
    public membreMetier: MembreMetier,
    public perimetreMetier: PerimetreMetier,
    public rootScope : GlobalVarsMetier,
    public techniqueMetier : TechniqueMetier,
    public dialogueMetier : DialogueMetier,
    public informationDestinataireMetier: InformationDestinataireMetier) 
    {
      this.loading = this.techniqueMetier.showLoadingProperTimes();


      this.trierParOrdreAlphabetique().then(tab =>  {
        this.tabSearch = tab;
        this.sortedUtilisateurs = tab;
      });
}
```

**My init function**

```
trierParOrdreAlphabetique()
{
    var deferred = new Promise(resolve => {
        this.showOtherButtons = false;
        this.loading.present();
        var deferredListerNotifications = new Promise<any>(resolveListerNotifications => {
            if(this.rootScope.perimetreConnecte == null)
            {
                this.utilisateurMetier.lister().then(tabUtilisateurs => {
                    resolveListerNotifications(tabUtilisateurs); 
                });
            }
            else
            {
                this.utilisateurMetier.listerByEspace(this.rootScope.perimetreConnecte.id).then(tabUtilisateurs => {
                        resolveListerNotifications(tabUtilisateurs); 
                });
            }
        });

        deferredListerNotifications.then(tabUtilisateurs =>
        {
            var sortedUtilisateurs = {};
            this.tabUtilisateurs = tabUtilisateurs;
            for(var i = 0; i < tabUtilisateurs.length; i++)
            {
                var utilisateur = tabUtilisateurs[i];
                var letter = utilisateur.nom.toUpperCase().charAt(0); 
                if(sortedUtilisateurs[letter] == undefined){
                    sortedUtilisateurs[letter] = [];
                }
                sortedUtilisateurs[letter].push(utilisateur);
            }
            this.isLoad = true;
            this.loading.dismiss();
            resolve(sortedUtilisateurs);
        });
    });

    return deferred;
}
```

Do you have any helpful ideas for me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### Issue

You have issue with same reference of Array.

> ### Fix

Its pretty simple to handle this kind of cases by creating the deep cloning the `Object` or `Array`.

```
constructor(
    public nav: NavController,
    public params: NavParams, 
    public utilisateurMetier : UtilisateurMetier, 
    public membreMetier: MembreMetier,
    public perimetreMetier: PerimetreMetier,
    public rootScope : GlobalVarsMetier,
    public techniqueMetier : TechniqueMetier,
    public dialogueMetier : DialogueMetier,
    public informationDestinataireMetier: InformationDestinataireMetier) 
    {
      this.loading = this.techniqueMetier.showLoadingProperTimes();


      this.trierParOrdreAlphabetique().then(tab =>  {
        this.tabSearch = tab;
        this.sortedUtilisateurs = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tab)); //create clone
      });
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tab))` would keep the properties, but won't keep the methods (since it's now an `object` instead of an instance of the class it was before). One way to prevent this from happening would be to clone the array by doing `let newArray = oldArray.slice()` in order to return a *shallow copy* of it.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like in your case the "tab" (result) that gets assigned to two other vars inside the constructor is actually a js object? So as the others explained in this case you assign reference to the same obj.

Since the object's properties's values seem to be arrays you need to create a clone of such object accordingly. I would use something like this:

```
  snapshot(object) {
    if (object == null || typeof (object) != 'object') return object;
    let temp = new object.constructor();
    for (var key in object) {
      if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        temp[key] = this.snapshot(object[key]);
      }
    }
    return temp;
  };
```

then in your method:

```
this.trierParOrdreAlphabetique().then(tab =>  {
        this.tabSearch = this.snapshot(tab);
        this.sortedUtilisateurs = this.snapshot(tab);
});
```